# when call an btn click method on enter key press Error accured " An Obeject reference is required for non-static field, method or property"

Tags: c#

[This is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQFls.png)

i just want to call btn click method when user press enter after entering data into textbox

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please provide some code snippet so everyone  may help you better!

Comment: Better design, extract the logic in your button click into a separate method and call that!

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab screenshot contains code... check it .. both method are visible

Comment: On your question you cannot call an event method since it will only listen to a button click, the error says that the event method is not valid in the given context. instead of calling the event try to use button_name.PerformClick() instead. here is some example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SJFJ you are right, in this way it will work, but i just want to do like this way... can you help me in this way

Comment: @SJFJ i used button name also but error says that "An object reference is required for non-static field , method or property"

Answer (score 0):

Do put logic in the event handler methods. Create separate functions and call them instead. Anything else is just bad design and even if there is a way to do it, don't start using bad practices from start.